# How can I parse this XML and map it properly?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, windows-phone-7

Here is the xml I want to parse:

```
<xml_api_reply version="1">
    <weather module_id="0" tab_id="0" mobile_row="0" mobile_zipped="1" row="0" section="0">
    <forecast_information>
    <city data="London UK"/>
    <postal_code data="London UK"/>
    <latitude_e6 data=""/>
    <longitude_e6 data=""/>
    <forecast_date data="2011-12-22"/>
    <current_date_time data="2011-12-22 14:50:00 +0000"/>
    <unit_system data="US"/>
    </forecast_information>
    <current_conditions>
    <condition data="Partly Cloudy"/>
    <temp_f data="54"/>
    <temp_c data="12"/>
    <humidity data="Humidity: 77%"/>
    <icon data="/ig/images/weather/partly_cloudy.gif"/>
    <wind_condition data="Wind: W at 10 mph"/>
    </current_conditions>
    <forecast_conditions>
    <day_of_week data="Thu"/>
    <low data="50"/>
    <high data="55"/>
    <icon data="/ig/images/weather/fog.gif"/>
    <condition data="Fog"/>
    </forecast_conditions>
    <forecast_conditions>
    <day_of_week data="Fri"/>
    <low data="37"/>
    <high data="55"/>
    <icon data="/ig/images/weather/chance_of_rain.gif"/>
    <condition data="Chance of Rain"/>
    </forecast_conditions>
    <forecast_conditions>
    <day_of_week data="Sat"/>
    <low data="45"/>
    <high data="48"/>
    <icon data="/ig/images/weather/mostly_sunny.gif"/>
    <condition data="Mostly Sunny"/>
    </forecast_conditions>
    <forecast_conditions>
    <day_of_week data="Sun"/>
    <low data="48"/>
    <high data="54"/>
    <icon data="/ig/images/weather/fog.gif"/>
    <condition data="Fog"/>
    </forecast_conditions>
    </weather>
    </xml_api_reply>
```

How can i parse and map this output properly? I'm struggling a bit. What I've tried to use is...

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<String>>> details =  
        new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>();
```

...to map each attribute data.

Comment: one way of doing it: http://www.dotnetperls.com/xelement

Answer (score 1):

You can deserialize directly using `datacontractserializer` and a class that matches the xml structure correctly or you can also use linq2xml using `XDocument` and cycle through each `XElement` in the `XDocument` and walk through it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create class hierarchy like in provided xml. For example class `Weather` contains another class `ForecastInformation` which has string fields `city`, `postal_code`, etc. Also, there are a list of `ForecastConditions` elements in `Weather` class for all temperature measurements